# How to open a new webpage using selenium on python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to get selenium to open a new web page, but it never works!

#### Error:

> `File "C:\Users\m11ro\OneDrive\Documents\test\Python Auto Bumper\test.py", line 31, in <module>
>       driver.get("ogusers.com/Thread-Can-anyone-give-me-a-job")
>     File "C:\Users\m11ro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
>       self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
>     File "C:\Users\m11ro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Users\m11ro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
>     (Session info: chrome=**.*.****.***)`

Answer (score 2):

change

```py
driver.get("ogusers.com/Thread-Can-anyone-give-me-a-job")
```

to

```py
driver.get("https://ogusers.com/Thread-Can-anyone-give-me-a-job")
```

always remember to make sure your url has a url scheme